# Multi-coloured tree plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, programming, graphs-and-networks, data-structures

I am trying to create a multi-coloured tree plot (Mathematica 9) where each branch is coloured according to its parent node value. For example, for a tree plot with three nodes, n1, n2 and n3, coming from a single parent node (n0), the children nodes of n1 should be red & n2 and n3 should be green.

```
TreePlot[nodes, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Red, Line[#1]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
     Row[{If[Last[#2] > 3, Rotate[Last[#2], 90 Degree], 
        Last[#2]]}], #1, Background -> White] &)]
```

[image: tree plot]

I am using the EdgeRenderingFunction for this within the following expression which will render the edges of the tree plot. The problem, I think, is that the If statement is not evaluated straight away and so the compiler does not recognise the first option (contained within the If statement) as a relevant one. As you can see I'm trying to create a tree plot with red and green branches.

```
TreePlot[nodes, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({If[Last[#2] == 1, Red, Green], 
     Line[#1]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
     Row[{If[Last[#2] > 3, Rotate[Last[#2], 90 Degree], 
        Last[#2]]}], #1, Background -> White] &)]
```

**The error message I get is:**

*If is not a Graphic Primitive or Directive*

[image]

Thanks for your time in helping me with this.

Comment: Does your code work for the edges if you comment out the `VertexRenderingFunction` part? What is your goal with the vertex rendering? The second parameter passed (`#2`) is the vertex name, so I'm not sure what your function is trying to do with that.

Comment: For a traditional tree there is a single root node, so why aren't all your branches the same color?

Comment: aardvark2012 - no, the code does not work if I comment out the VertexRenderingFunciton part. Davis G. Stork - Because each child node represents a different interrelated group. This can be done in the R programming language.

Comment: "coloured according to its parent node value" <- Where and how is this "parent node value" stored?  Can you provide sample data?  The error is no doubt because `==` does not evaluate. This indicates that you may have nodes with non-numerical names.  The fix may be as simple as using `===`, but I can't tell for sure without seeing a complete example (with data).

Comment: Szabolics - Here's a sample of the node list:  `{{0} -> {0, 1}, {0} -> {0, 2}, {0} -> {0, 3}, {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 4}, {0,
    1} -> {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 6}, {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 7}, {0, 
   1} -> {0, 1, 8}...`  The code works  with `===` or `TrueQ[If...]` instead of `==` (*Thanks!*) but I got an unexpected result - all edges were rendered the same colour. So either the `EdgeRenderingFunction` function renders the whole tree object rather than it's parts or I'll need to include the edge colour into the tree data structure (node table), or use a different way (function) to represent the tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be at least partially due to how you reference the arguments of `EdgeRenderingFunction`. We can label the edges with `Last[#2]` to see what we're working with:

```
nodes = {{0} -> {0, 1}, {0} -> {0, 2}, {0} -> {0, 3}, {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 4}, {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 6}, 
  {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 7}, {0, 1} -> {0, 1, 8}};
TreePlot[nodes, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Line[#1], 
     Inset[Last[#2], Mean[#1], Automatic, Automatic, #[[1]] - #[[2]], 
      Background -> White]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
     Row[{If[Last[#2] > 3, Rotate[Last[#2], 90 Degree], 
        Last[#2]]}], #1, Background -> White] &)]
```

[image]

So none of these are ever going to be 1. You could, of course, use these for your colouring. You could also use the values in `First[#2]`:

```
TreePlot[nodes, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Line[#1], 
     Inset[First[#2], Mean[#1], Automatic, Automatic, #[[1]] - #[[2]],
       Background -> White]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
     Row[{If[Last[#2] > 3, Rotate[Last[#2], 90 Degree], 
        Last[#2]]}], #1, Background -> White] &)]
```

[image]

You should be able to use any of these values to colour the edges however you want. For example, using `#2[[1, -1]]` for your condition gives:

```
TreePlot[nodes, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({If[#2[[1, -1]] == 1, Red, Green], 
     Line[#1]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
     Row[{If[Last[#2] > 3, Rotate[Last[#2], 90 Degree], 
        Last[#2]]}], #1, Background -> White] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation

Answer (score 4):

You code uses rules for edge styles, e.g.:

```
func[elist_, pn_, col_] := 
 Module[{rules = 
    MapThread[ed_[#1, x_] :> Style[ed[#1, x], #2] &, {pn, col}]},
  elist /. rules]
```

For example:

```
TreeGraph[
 func[{0 -> 1, 0 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6}, {0, 1, 
   2}, {Red, Green, {Purple, Thick, Dashed}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ubpdqn for this example.

Answer (score 2):

There are simpler ways to do this.  I do not have Mathematica 9 around, but I *think* this should work.

First, I recommend representing trees as directed graphs. This way the identity of the root vertex is already encoded.  `IGDirectedTree` from IGraph/M is useful for this (Mathematica 10.0+ only), otherwise you can do a `BreadthFirstScan`.

Consider this directed tree:

```
tree = Graph@{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 2 -> 8, 
    4 -> 9, 2 -> 10, 2 -> 11, 1 -> 12, 12 -> 13, 2 -> 14, 13 -> 15, 
    2 -> 16, 2 -> 17, 9 -> 18, 4 -> 19, 11 -> 20};
```

Now simply use patterns to select a set of edges to colour:

```
Graph[tree,
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name",
 EdgeStyle -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] _ -> Red, 2 \[DirectedEdge] _ -> Blue, 4 \[DirectedEdge] _ -> Green, 12 \[DirectedEdge] _ -> Orange}
 ]
```

[image]

Having a directed tree was useful because we could easily distinguish "down-edges" (away from the root) from "up-edges" (towards the root).

If you do not want the arrowheads displayed, add

```
EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line",
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
```

Like this:

```
Graph[tree,
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name",
 EdgeStyle -> {Thick, (1 \[DirectedEdge] _) -> Red, 2 \[DirectedEdge] _ -> Blue, 4 \[DirectedEdge] _ -> Green, 12 \[DirectedEdge] _ -> Orange},
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line",
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
]
```

[image]